# Ajax won't send data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**SOLVED:** The code posted here was correct, but some of the PHP code connecting to the database needed fixing, I have it working now. I used *Quentin*'s suggestions in the comments to fix my problem.

I'm trying to send a JSON of an array through ajax to a PHP file, then have the php file run. This is my ajax:

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + selectedImageArray );

  });
});
```

In my PHP file I connect to a database then have this:

```
$array = $_POST['selectedImageArray'];
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pending_trades (steam_id, trade_items, is_giving, is_receiving, has_started) VALUES (:steamid, :itemlist, '1', '0', '0')");
    $sql->bindParam(':steamid', $steamprofile['steamid']);
    $sql->bindParam(':itemlist', $array);

    $sql->execute();
```

I want this to send the "selectedImageArray" json to the php and run the msql query using it on the press of this button:

```
<button id="submit" class="button1" >Submit<span></span></button>
```

When the button is clicked, I get the "data saved: `array data`" message, but the php code isn't run. Why isn't this working?

**EDIT:** I set `data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}` instead of `data: selectedImageArray` because I was told it makes it into JSON format, is that correct?

Comment: Where is `$steamprofile['steamid']` coming from? Remove `include()`

Comment: I've never seen `include()` in JavaScript before...  Regardless, where specifically does this fail?  When you debug the PHP code, what happens?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, why would they need to make the request synchronous? It isn't needed here and would lock up the UI till it is done.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, Even if the data was image data (which would require `data` be a FormData object) making the request synchronous wouldn't affect it.

Comment: I removed the include, I didn't think that was right. `$steamprofile['steamid']` comes from another .php file which is included in `submit.php`. 

Also, the array is just characters. (The name of images)

Comment: How can you tell the PHP code isn't run? And what does that mean anyway? Does the Net tab of the developer tools not show the request being made? Does it timeout instead of getting a response? Do it get a response but that shows PHP source code? Does the wrong branch of an `if` statement get run?

Comment: "because I was told it makes it into JSON format, is that correct?" — No, that will make it form encoded data (which is what the PHP code you've written is trying to read). It won't be JSON but it will be what you want.

Comment: @Quentin Okay. I thought the PHP code wasn't run because if it worked, it should make a new log into the database. I know that the PHP works as well, because I have tested it by itself and it makes a log into the DB, just with nothing where `$array` should be. I just checked in the Network tab and it is saying it's conecting to `submit.php` via `POST`. That is the only indication I can see that it is connecting to `submit.php`, though I still think it isn't running the file's code.

Comment: @MitchCool1 — Simply the code for debugging then. Make it just echo something. Look in the Response part of the Net tab of your developer tools to see if there is any data there. Build the code back up. Add debugging statements to make sure the values you have in your variables are the values you expect.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, solved now. I did that and found that I had to include() another file to get the rest of the code to run.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding in database an array not an string try to use:

```
$sql->bindParam(':itemlist', json_encode($array));
```

and when you get the data just run:

```
$array = json_decode($itemlist);
```

Comment: That's a horrible solution to the problem. Relational databases are great because they can do relations. If that *is* the problem (which isn't clear because the OP still hasn't defined the problem properly) then the solution is to set up a table with a foreign key and then insert values on a loop.

Comment: your solution is better only if the OP needs to use an query to get relational data, if he needs to get all the data per id is faster this way.

Comment: That's a false economy. Denormalised data inevitably turns out to be a problem 6 months down the line.

Comment: @Quentin So you don't think I should encode the data into a JSON? It would save some space if I did.

Comment: @Macerier You seem to be right. Using `$array` adds only the word "Array", converting it to a Json saves the actual array.

Comment: @MitchCool1 — I have trouble believing that any space saving would be significant. (And if you really have a space problem then a bigger hard disk would be a better solution).

Comment: @Quentin yes it could convert in an problem

Comment: @MitchCool1 encoding data in json could help or not. If you want (at any moment - now or later) to do an query for some specific data like ho has this specific image saved you need an different table like Quentin proposed. If you only want to store data use json_encode - this works for storing and retrieving not for relational use.

Answer (score -1):

You can add content type JSON. other wise it will consider as text.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray});
 $.ajax({
method: "POST",
dataType: 'json', // If your response is JSON
contentType: "application/json",
url: "submit.php",
data: data
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + selectedImageArray );
include ('submit.php');
});
```

Comment: Setting `dataType` just affects how the response from the server would be handled, it would not affect how the php code is run

Comment: We can't see what the response from the server is, so we don't know if it is JSON. The client code only treats it as text anyway.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` is just plain wrong — the value of `data` isn't JSON and the server side code is reading from `$_POST` so the server isn't expecting JSON.

Comment: I set the contentType as json

Comment: how can you use php in ajax javascript without starting or ending php

Comment: @AnilTalla — Yes, that is a problem. You set the content-type to JSON but you didn't set the content to JSON (so you are lying) and the server isn't trying to read JSON.

Comment: @Quentin Ya, I added this line JSON.stringify({selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray});

Comment: @AnilTalla — Which now means you aren't lying, but it still won't work because `$_POST['selectedImageArray']` won't be populated because PHP doesn't handle JSON formatted HTTP requests that way. Since the server side code is using `$_POST` you're still adding an additional bug instead of solving the problem.

Comment: @Quentin . Okay, i dont know about PHP. I Know about ajax.

Answer (score -1):

First of all look at your browser debugger of what is really sent to the php file. Second thing: You will send JSON to it. That means, that you have an POST form Array like this:

```
[{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
}]
```

So, in conclusion this does not work:

```
$array = $_POST['selectedImageArray'];
```

You need to access e. g. `$_POST['key1']` directly.

Comment: "You will send JSON to it." — That isn't true. jQuery will generate form encoded data and populate `$_POST` when given the syntax in the question.